# populate repeated element of proto

Tags: java, mongodb, grpc-java

Attempting to generate dept arrays, here's my attempt.

Proto file

```
service DepartmentService {
    rpc findAll(Request) returns (Response);
}

message Department {
    int64 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}

message Request {
    string id = 1;
}

message Response {
    int32 code = 1;
    repeated Department departments = 2;
}
```

Corresponding java code.

```
public void findAll(DepartmentOuter.Request request, StreamObserver<DepartmentOuter.Response> responseObserver) {
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = database
            .getCollection("department")
            .find()
            .iterator();

    DepartmentOuter.Response.Builder builder = DepartmentOuter.Response.newBuilder();
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        Document document = cursor.next();

        DepartmentOuter.Department department = DepartmentOuter.Department
                .newBuilder()
                .setId(Integer.parseInt(document.getString("_id")))
                .setName(document.getString("name")).build();

        builder.addDepartments(department);


    }



responseObserver.onNext(DepartmentOuter.Response.newBuilder().setCode(0).setDepartments(builder).build());
}
```

I've the problem in the last line for this piece of code. How to send the populate output to the client?

responseObserver.onNext(DepartmentOuter.Response.newBuilder().setCode(0).setDepartments(builder).build());

---

**Edit - after the rename**

proto file

```
service DepartmentService {
    rpc findAll(Request) returns (Response);
}

message Department {
    int64 id = 1;
    string name = 2;
}

message Request {
    string id = 1;
}

message Response {
    int32 code = 1;
    repeated Department department = 2;
}

@Override
public void findAll(DepartmentOuter.Request request, StreamObserver<DepartmentOuter.Response> responseObserver) {
    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = database
            .getCollection("department")
            .find()
            .iterator();

    DepartmentOuter.Response.Builder builder = DepartmentOuter.Response.newBuilder();
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        Document document = cursor.next();

        DepartmentOuter.Department department = DepartmentOuter.Department
                .newBuilder()
                .setId(Integer.parseInt(document.getString("_id")))
                .setName(document.getString("name")).build();

        builder.addDepartment(department);
    }

    responseObserver.onNext(DepartmentOuter.Response.newBuilder().setCode(0).setDepartment.build());
}
```

[image]

Comment: Just FYI, you are recommended to use singular names for repeated fields, e.g. `department`, so you get `addDepartment`, `addAllDepartments` etc as method names.

Comment: ok, I'll rename it

Comment: please see the edit after the rename, and the screenshot for the possible values.

Comment: What don't you understand about the autocomplete messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
responseObserver.onNext(DepartmentOuter.Response.newBuilder().setCode(0).setDepartments(builder).build());
```

`departments` is a repeated field, so it should be `addDepartments` rather than `setDepartments`. You could invoke `setDepartments(someIndex, someDepartment)`, but that only works if you have previously added at least `someIndex+1` values to the builder; you haven't, as it's a new builder.

But `builder` is a `DepartmentOuter.Response.Builder` anyway, not a `Department`, so this wouldn't work either. It's not clear what you're intending to do; perhaps:

```
responseObserver.onNext(builder.setCode(0).build());
```

Comment: I think this is what i needed, `responseObserver.onNext(builder.setCode(0).build());`, testing

Comment: any thoughts on `.setId(document.getObjectId("_id").toString())` code, it's throwing `org.bson.types.ObjectId cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.String`, id is a string in my proto.

Comment: I think that `getString` requires that the thing you specify is really a `String`. You need to work out how to get the string you want from the thing that isn't a `String`.